# Scanner and Pipe Delimited File Java

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I am using a pipe delimited `.txt` file with scheduled flights.  I need to break up each line into its 3 separate parts, `scheduledTime`, `eventType` and `flightID` an example flight within the `.txt` file would look like:

12:00|ARRIVAL|A001

I have it working for one single flight but when I add more I get this error

Full Trace:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'ARRIVAL' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.time.LocalTime.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.time.LocalTime.parse(Unknown Source)
at edu.metrostate.ics240.p4.gaw886.sim.AirportSimulator.processEventFile(AirportSimulator.java:49)
at edu.metrostate.ics240.p4.gaw886.sim.tests.AirportSimTests.testScenarioOne(AirportSimTests.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

now I understand what is happening here, when I have more than one flight it is skipping over the scheduledTime piece in the second line and trying to parse the eventType instead.  I cannot figure out how to fix this.  Below are my methods:

Method to create the event file:

```
public static final double DEPARTURE_PROB = 0.20;
public static final double ARRIVAL_PROB = 0.15;
public static final int ARR_RESERVE_TIME = 2;
public static final int DEP_RESERVE_TIME = 3;
public static final int SIM_MINUTES = 60;
public static final long SEED = 20170620001L;
public static final Random RAND = new Random(SEED);
public static final String DELIM = "\\|";

public static void genEventFile(String fileName, double arrivalProbability, double departureProbability,
        int minutes) {
    int arrFlightId = 1;
    int depFlightId = 1;
    try (PrintWriter simFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);) {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("00:00");

        for (int i = 0; i < minutes; i++) {
            if (RAND.nextDouble() <= arrivalProbability) {
                simFile.printf("%s|%s|%s\n", time.plusMinutes(i), Event.EventType.ARRIVAL,
                        String.format("A%03d", arrFlightId++));
            }
            if (RAND.nextDouble() <= departureProbability) {
                simFile.printf("%s|%s|%s\n", time.plusMinutes(i), Event.EventType.DEPARTURE,
                        String.format("D%03d", depFlightId++));
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the method to process the event file:

```
    public void processEventFile(String filename) {
    LocalTime scheduledTime = null;
    EventType eventType;
    String flightID;
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename)).useDelimiter(DELIM);) {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            scheduledTime = LocalTime.parse(scanner.next());
            eventType = EventType.valueOf(scanner.next());
            flightID = scanner.next();
            flight = new Flight(scheduledTime, eventType, flightID);
            flightQueue.add(flight);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So my question is how do I make the scanner move to the next line after reading the `flightId` and not think that the `flightId` of line 1 and `scheduledTime` of line two are on the same line?

Sample flight data:

```
00:02|DEPARTURE|D001
00:03|ARRIVAL|A001
00:03|DEPARTURE|D002
00:04|DEPARTURE|D003
00:06|DEPARTURE|D004
00:09|DEPARTURE|D005
00:12|ARRIVAL|A002
00:14|ARRIVAL|A003
00:16|DEPARTURE|D006
00:18|ARRIVAL|A004
00:21|DEPARTURE|D007
00:22|ARRIVAL|A005
00:24|DEPARTURE|D008
00:28|ARRIVAL|A006
00:28|DEPARTURE|D009
00:30|ARRIVAL|A007
00:41|ARRIVAL|A008
00:44|DEPARTURE|D010
00:47|DEPARTURE|D011
00:48|DEPARTURE|D012
00:53|DEPARTURE|D013
00:54|ARRIVAL|A009
00:54|DEPARTURE|D014
00:56|DEPARTURE|D015
00:57|DEPARTURE|D016
```

Comment: Could you use a BufferedReader? Then you could read a line at a time and use String.split(regex) to split each line into its components

Comment: Can you post sample txt file with flight id and time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Scanner` object is only parsing the file based on your`DELIM` variable `|`. It isn't splitting the file by the new line character as well.

You could use a `BufferedReader` object to read the file line by line and then split the text later on. Something like this:

```
public void processEventFile(String fileName) {
     String line;
     String[] split;
     BufferedReader reader = null;
     try {
          reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
          while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               split = line.split("\\|");
               flightQueue.add(new Flight(split[0], split[1], split[2]));
          }
     } catch(IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
          if(reader != null) {
               try {
                    reader.close();
               } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you delimiter to use OR condition.

```
public static final String DELIM = "[\\||\n]+";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Scanner` to read file line by line. In example I use `try-with-resources` block to make sure `Scanner` is closed. Method `forEachRemaining` returns next line of input file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(NewMain.class.getResourceAsStream("airport.txt"))) {
            sc.forEachRemaining(s -> {
                System.out.println(s.length() + " " + s);
            });
        }
    }
```